# Custom Render not being used on Bindable property update

Tags: xamarin.forms, custom-renderer, xaml-binding

Please consider the following issue.

In my Xamarin.Forms app I have a custom render for UWP that allows for a button to have two lines, and be centralised.

The buttons in questions are items in a Listview that are bound to objects. When they are initially generated, they display correctly with both lines of text in the center of the button, however if I update the text, it updates, but seems to bypass the custom renders "be in the center" code.

Please see the below code snippets and images to explain the situation further.

**Custom Render**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TwoLinedButton), typeof(TwoLinedButtonUWP))]
namespace aphiresawesomeproject.UWP
{
    public class TwoLinedButtonUWP : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null && e.NewElement.Text != null)
            {
                var textBlock = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock
                {
                    Text = e.NewElement.Text,
                    TextAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.TextAlignment.Center,
                    TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWholeWords
                };
                Control.Content = textBlock;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ListView x:Name="AphiresListView" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewItems}" Margin="0,20,0,0" RowHeight="130" SeparatorVisibility="None" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row ="3" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <local:TwoLinedButton Command="{Binding ClickedCommand}" Margin="5,10,5,10" HorizontalOptions ="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="{Binding color_hex}" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="{StaticResource LightTextColor}" FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding problem_title}"></local:TwoLinedButton>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Update in Viewmodel**

```
foreach (AphiresObject ViewItem in ListViewItems)
{
    ViewItem.problem_title = ViewItem.problem_title.Replace("Line 2", "Updated Line 2");
}
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you need to do is `override OnElementPropertyChanged` in your renderer and set the textBlock properties again when your text property changes.

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    if (e.PropertyName == TwoLinedButton.TextProperty.PropertyName)
    {
        //Set text block properties
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks for your time on this. When I drop that code snippet in I appear not to have access to e.NewElement, so not sure how to set the Text parameter of the Textblock (updated comment as I see you dropped in an edit, thanks!)

Comment: Thanks for the update, i've edited my above comment. Cheers!

Comment: `Control` and `Element` should both be found in `OnElementPropertyChanged` you just might need to check to make sure they're not null

Comment: Perfect, you are a gent. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to tell the view to re-render itself.

```
iOS: this.SetNeedsDisplay();

Android: this.Invalidate();
```